# How to calibrate captured images(stills) from a camera using Open CV?

Tags: matlab, opencv, camera-calibration, aruco

Recently I have captured some images of my Charuco board. Different angles and reflection of the shots were also captured.

However i have been only using the calibrate Charuco cpp to do some test calibrations for my intrinsics and extrinsics through a webcam. 
Is there a way to alter the script to using captured images or a alternative way to upload captured shots using Open CV.

I am currently using the calibrate Charuco Camera cpp in Open CV to calibrate the board through a webcam originally. This is shown below in

```
https://github.com/kumakier/calibrationStuff/blob/master/calibrate_Camera_Charuco
```

I tried Matlab toolkit but it seems to work brilliant for just chessboard images but it does give me a rough estimate on my camera parameters and i am unsure thats really efficient to use when dealing with Charuco(which uses Aruco markers). As for Open cv i tried changing the input where it calls the Video for capturing screenshots.

Running the test on matlab using the toolkit gave me the following results

### Intrinsics

```
>Focal length (pixels):   [ 6630.3128 +/- 11.5933    6641.9512 +/- 11.4436 ]
>
>Principal point (pixels):[ 2225.6366 +/- 6.7927     1324.1855 +/- 6.9771  ]
>
>Radial distortion:       [   -0.1640 +/- 0.0083       -0.1912 +/- 0.0904  ]
>
```

This is however with it just detecting the corners in the Charuco, it doesnt pick up the ids. So  i am unsure if i can trust this method.

This is my first post here, if there is anything missing let me know :D.

Comment: [cv::imread](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) loads image files from disk.
In the reference code, [this](https://github.com/kumakier/calibrationStuff/blob/master/calibrate_Camera_Charuco#L227) is where image is obtained from camera. I suppose you intend to replaced that to obtain images from disk instead of camera.

Comment: What is the resolution of webcam used? If the values of principal point are correct, then I would expect the resolution of the camera would be bit higher than [4K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution)